# SCSS/SASS files doesn't work with electron nuxt

Tags: vue.js, electron, nuxt.js, node-sass, sass-loader

I don't know how to fix this, the header and script tag is just rendered in electron app. i've already tried many things but nothing comes work. this is the screenshot. btw, i'm using this template https://github.com/saltyshiomix/nuxtron. if i exclude the scss file, it works. but i need to working with scss. i already added node-sass and sass-loader previously. how to fix this issue? thanks.

[image: all tags are rendered in electron app]

***the nuxt.config.js file***

```js
export default {
  // ssr: false,
  head: {
    title: 'this is broken app',
    meta: [
      { charset: "utf-8" },
      { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
      {
        hid: "description",
        name: "description",
        content: process.env.npm_package_description || "it has been drive me crazy like days"
      }
    ],
    link: [
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href:
          "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,800;1,400&family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;1,400;1,500&display=swap"
      }
    ]
  },
  loading: { color: "#F4841A" },
  css: [
    "~/assets/scss/main.scss"
  ],
  plugins: [
    // {src: '~/plugins/element.js', mode: 'client'},
  ],
  buildModules: [
    // '@nuxtjs/fontawesome',
  ],
  /*
   ** Axios module configuration
   ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
   */
  axios: {
    // baseURL: process.env.AUTH_API,
    retry: { retries: 3 }
    // proxy: true
  },
  build: {
    extend: (config) => {
      config.target = 'electron-renderer';
    },
  },
}
```

***the scss file***

```css
* {
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Verdana", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 0px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

***project structure***

[image: project structure]

Comment: is your bundler is configured for using your sass-loader?

Comment: @Deniz where do I configure this? I couldn't find any webpack configuration js file like electron-vue does.

Answer (score -1):

The weird thing is, I created fresh project, same error, make it again over and over, now it worked. I think there's some problem with importing and config @nuxtjs/fontawesome plugin in nuxt.config.js but that's weird. Anyway, when it worked, it worked, right? :D